# Android Package Structure Best Practice

Tags: android, package

I have a question regarding best practices for application package structure.

I watched Reto Meier's Google I/O 2011 presentation ["Android Protips: Advanced Topics for Expert Android Developer](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-protips-advanced-topics-for-expert-android-app-developers.html)s" and read his blog post "[A Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/)" and noted his application package structure of:

com. ... .content_providers
   com. ... .receivers
   com. ... .services
   com. ... .UI
   com. ... .UI.fragments
   com. ... .utils
   com. ... .utils.base

Is this the preferred structure for packages?  Is there a better structure?

Comment: Really love these kind of questions. Would be also interested to know what other people think about that

Comment: It's not entirely the same, but this question might be useful in a more general sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525872/android-project-package-structure

Comment: I like this way, I categorize my packages by what the main function of the classes in them are, too. Like *.activities -- This is subjective though.

Comment: I have explained [Pros and cons of  different package structures in Android apps](http://onetouchcode.com/2016/11/06/package-structure-android-apps/). This might be useful.

Answer (score 6):

The main goal of packaging your classes is to simplify the navigation through your source code. This is especially important for open source applications. In my opinion, a easy-to-navigate package structure includes the following packages:

`com.example.main` - contains your main driver functions, such as your main activity(s), your application class (if you have one), etc

`com.example.conf` - contains your configuration files, such as those containing constants (static final variables)

`com.example.net` - network-related classes, such as those that make http requests

`com.example.util` - utility classes, such as services, BroadcastReceivers, or other background processes

Comment: that's one of the purposes of packages, but not necessarily the main one. the other is to properly hide areas of concern. for example, you can make all of your UI code in the .ui package, make all of the classes pkg private, and not expose them to any other layer of the code.

Comment: I see a lot of projects structured in that way (I think even Google IO 2012 is). I like my project grouped (packaged) by subject: (com.apps.player with PlayerActivity, PlayerListView, PlayerListAdapter, com.apps.sync with SyncService, SyncHelper, etc.)
I find the code easier to navigate and to understand in that way. Also, if I work on a specific feature I have all classes at hand.
I don't understand why anyone puts classes that indicate their function in their name (eg. PlayerActivity) into packages that indicate their classes functions (eg. com.apps.activities).