# Am I using packages incorrectly?

Tags: java, android, package

I'm building an android chat app.
I've been using packages to store similar classes together, but I'm not sure this is right now. 
I've been doing this:

```
com.myApp.adapters        //- All my ListAdapters     (FriendsListAdapter, MessagesListAdapter)
com.myApp.fragments       //- All my Fragments        (FriendsFragment, ConversationFragment)
com.myApp.database       //- All my Database classes (DatabaseHelper, MessagesDataSource, etc...)
com.myApp.models         //- All my Models           (Friend, Message, Conversation)
com.myApp.communications  //- All my Comms classes    (GCM classes, Facebook Classes, etc...)
```

Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Or should it be more like:

```
com.myApp.Conversations  //- Everything for Conversations (MessageListAdapter, ConversationFragment, MessagesDatasource)
com.myApp.Friends        //- Everything for Friends (FriendsListAdapter, FriendsFragment, FriendsDataSource)
```

//  ...and so on.

I suspect it should be the latter, packages based on a function or feature of the application itself, rather than grouping the classes by what they have in common with each other, if that makes sense?

EDIT: 
Actually, are both the above wrong, I should define the subsystems right from the start, so more like this:

```
com.myApp.UserInterface
com.myApp.Database
com.myApp.Communications
```

Which in terms of individual classes is a mix of both the above, but each package is a clear defined subsystem. In which case, where would things like Models fit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Package Structure Best Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617067/android-package-structure-best-practice)

Comment: i usually design package, using the first approach in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, both the ways are correct. Its completely depends on you that which style you using to store classes inside packages. First Structure, is wuite clear and easy to understand technical aspects, because after month if you will see in your code then you easily can understand that your all adapters are in adapter package and so on. Second, it completely shows that your conversation related things are in conversation package and friends are in friends package.

But as per me, I suggest you to use first one. Because its very easy to understand and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **second approach** will be better,because this will make your code more modular,You can test your code in parts,you will know up front that what functionality you may put on hold and what to execute later,However in first one,Its not bad but I am not seeing any benefit of using it.

(*Considering you are not developing some Open source application)*

---

Answer (score 1):

The first one is more preferred because as per the conventions it has defined , and second thing is like the similar components are under one group is also good approach which you have defined in the first statement

**FYI**

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html
```