# How to organize package in android?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I read package-by-feature in http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205 and liked it. So when apply it in my project, i have two problems:

1. When an activity have more than one feature
2. When a feature can be used by more activities (anywhere in my app)

How to solve two problems above? or You can send me an other way to organize package?

Thank u :D

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7083121/6414107

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Package Structure Best Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617067/android-package-structure-best-practice)